# jquery tokeninput field is cleared when there are other validation error(s) when submitting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jquery tokeninput to select multiple items coming from the database, using autocompletion as they try to find each item. However, if there are validation errors in other fields when submitting the form, the tokeninput field is cleared and the user's got to select the items again. My worry now is to persist the selected item even if there are validation errors in other fields.

Here's my script

```
 $("#States").tokenInput("/User/getPreferredStates",
 {
    placeholder: 'Primary Skills',
    preventDuplicates: true,
    theme: 'facebook',
    tokenValue: 'name',
 });
```

and my html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "SignUp", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    [...]
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.States, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control,text-box", id= "States" })
    </div>
   [...]
```

Comment: Where your validation is implemented? If it is on server side then you basically refreshing your page/form when submitting, that's why it erases all input fields. Do if before you submit your form in jQuery or use AJAX to pass data to server

Comment: @JavaEvgen it does not erase all input fields. It's only the tokeninput field that is erased